# Set the $HOME path in Docker

Tags: python, docker

I have a python file which sets the value as $HOME variable

```
from pathlib import Path    

path = str(Path.home())
```

If I run it locally, the `path` becomes `C:/Users/BlueMango`, however If I run it in docker `path` has value `/home/imageName`. How do I set it to the user's `$HOME`? `path` has the files I want to read from, so currently it works for me locally, but it fails if I run it in docker because `/home/imageName` does not have files.

We can assume that any user who runs the dockerfile has the file in their `$HOME` folder.

EDIT: Using volume solved the issue, Thanks!

Comment: You have to use volumes: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: I got it, can you please give an concrete example of how to use it? Thanks

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://github.com/mkowsiak/coarrays-docker - this file `~/your_fortran_code` (on your local system) will be visible as `/home/fortcoder/code` inside Docker container.

Comment: A container can't directly access the host user's files, environment variables or otherwise, and if that's the primary goal of your application you might find it easier to use a non-Docker host Python.

Comment: How do you run the container? `docker run`? `docker-compose`? `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that any user who runs the Dockerfile has the file in their $HOME folder you could just add a COPY line in your Dockerfile to copy the required files from your $HOME path to the Docker's $HOME path.

The line to be added would be like:

```
COPY <src> <dest>
```

Being *src* the directory from where you run the Docker command and *dest* you could leave it as /home/imageName

Comment: surely using "C:/Users/BlueMango" is not a good idea ?

Comment: as suggested previously in your comments, I think if you want that you can use Volumes, but being 1 single file that apparently will be required by every Docker container you create with that Dockerfile, I think its easier to just create a copy of the file on creation of each container.

Comment: "C:/Users/BlueMango" will be invalid for other users, no? They will have their name instead of  `Bluemango`

Comment: I think I don't get what you mean by users. Every Docker container running will get this Python file from their own directory. 

The Python file you have in C:/Users/BlueMango will be copied in whichever directory of the Docker container you specify in the <dest> field of the COPY statement I passed you in the reply.

Comment: COPY <src> <dest> should be in dockerfile, but in dockerfile I have the address `C:/Users/BlueMango` as `src`, which is invalid for others. Is that not a problem? Sorry, I am a novice

Comment: Yeah, you should change src to . so the Dockerfile fetches for the file in your current directory where you have the Dockerfile, this way it will work for whoever uses this Dockerfile